# Pymysql Sql stance having Variable

Tags: python, format, pymysql

```
 if difficulty == 1:
                    cursor = tetris.cursor()
                    name2 = chr(name[0]) + chr(name[1]) + chr(name[2])
                    sql = "INSERT INTO Normal (id, score) VALUES ({name2}.format(name2), 404)"
                    cursor.execute(sql)
                    tetris.commit()  
                    cursor.close()
```

It's my code to insert game Id and Score to db.
but {name2}.format(name2) isn't work for me..
I do not hava any idea to solve it.
What's the problem ?

Comment: By "isn't work', what do you mean?  Also where is ```name``` defined?  What exactly did you want to do with ```{name2}.format(name2)```?

Comment: @ewong when I use sql with {name2}.format(name2), the sql show me error and name = [65, 65, 65], the ASCII code to show Alphabet It has name[name_location], so when the event K_RIGHT evokes the name_location +1 >> change Alphabet

Comment: `"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '}.format(name2), 404)' at line 1")' `

Comment: You're not using a format string correctly, I think you should be using `sql = f"INSERT INTO Normal (id, score) VALUES ({name2}, 404)"` which, if `name` is `[65, 65, 65]` will evaluate to `'INSERT INTO Normal (id, score) VALUES (AAA, 404)'`.

Comment: Is there any link with the pygame library?